# How to show Apple Pay in my setting menu on iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: ios, applepay

I want to integrated Apple pay with Stripe. I have updated provisioning profile to use Apple pay. I am using iPhone 6 plus device with updates version 8.1.1 iOS . My problem is that I can't see Passbook & Apple Pay menu item in my device's setting menu. That's why I'm unable to test apple pay. I have also tried changing Region to US, but it didn't show up there.

Check below image has apple pay menu in setting.
[image]

[Apple Pay: Official Document](http://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201239)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GO to Setting > General > Language & Region > United State**